# EntLib V6 Logging within a Windows Service

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

I have a windows service which uses ELAB as logging. When running the service in console mode all logging works fine. But as soon as I start it as a service no logging occurs.

Things I have checked:

- checked folder permissions and
- ran the service in console mode from the user which is used by the service
- used PROCMON to check if there was even a try to create a logfile
- used absolute and relative path to specify the logfile

I have no clue why this does not work.

To initialize logging:

```
try
{
    var config = new SystemConfigurationSource(true, 30000);
    var logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(config);
    LogWriter = logWriterFactory.Create();
    Logger.SetLogWriter(LogWriter, false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var msg = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} Error loading configuration. {ex}";
    File.WriteAllText(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%\\mayflower_logging_error.txt"), msg);
    Debug.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

And my ELAB configuration:

```
<enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="Mayflower">
    <sources>
        <add name="Mayflower"
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.SystemConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </sources>
</enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
<loggingConfiguration name="ServiceLogging" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General"
                      logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false" revertImpersonation="false">
    <listeners>
        <add name="Logfile"
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             fileName="Logs\Mayflower-Server.log" footer="::: Message End :::"
             formatter="Detailed" header="" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
             rollInterval="Midnight" rollSizeKB="50000" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime"
             asynchronous="true" />
        <add
            listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            type="Mayflower.Server.Core.ConsoleTraceListener, Mayflower.Server.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            filter="Information" name="Console" formatter="Short" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
        <add
            type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            template="{timestamp} {category} {message}{newline}    Priority: {priority} EventId: {eventid} Severity: {severity} Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}    Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
            name="Detailed" />
        <add
            type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            template="{timestamp(FixedFormatTime)} {category} {message}{newline}"
            name="Short" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
        <add switchValue="All" name="General">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Console" />
                <add name="Logfile" />
            </listeners>
        </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
        <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Logfile" />
                <add name="Console" />
            </listeners>
        </allEvents>
        <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Console" />
                <add name="Logfile" />
            </listeners>
        </notProcessed>
        <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Logfile" />
                <add name="Console" />
            </listeners>
        </errors>
    </specialSources>
</loggingConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind. I finally found the problem. My Console mode started the actual code, while in service mode my code was not invoked - hence no logging :).